# Azure blazor app intermittent error after few minutes of inactivity

Tags: .net-core, websocket, signalr, blazor, azure-signalr

I have created a blazor web app . I have set up the websocket using azure signal r service. I am facing 3 intermittent issues

1.After few minutes of Inactivity I am getting

> Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.

2.Intermittently I am getting following error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504
> (Gateway Time-out)

3. I am getting another error after jsruntime invocation

> Error: Circuit has been shut down due to error.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check resources in Azure portal if app is not being sent to rest.

Comment: How I can check the same?